# javascript react app fails to compile with generated openapi-client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, openapi

I've created a React App (written in js) and now I want to add an openapi client which is generated via SwaggerCodegen but it fails to compile.

I've generated the client for js via:

```sh
docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/specs" swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli-v3 generate -i /specs/myapi.json -o /specs/myapi-client -l javascript
```

In the generated Readme it says, that you can push the generated client code to a git repository and add it as a dependency from there, which I've done via `npm install <me>/<my-repo> --save`. But now when I run `npm start` as before, I get the following error:

```
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4yQ) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

So I tried exactly this. In different forums they described, that you have to add to your *package.json* something like the following and have to install the *@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties*.

```json
"babel": {
   "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
      ],
   "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
}
```

I also tried to work with a babel.config.js file and I added the option `{"loose": true}` to the plugins-section. But whatever I tried - the error during the compiling stayed.

How can I fix this compilation error to get the client to work in my react frontend?

Comment: Do you have a *babel.config.js* file? If not, you can create one at the root of your project. If you already do, try adding the plugins array there.

Comment: I also tried this. But it didn't change anything.